# Почему вместо квадрата залитого цветом WinApi рисует квадрат заполненный чёрными точками?

Tags: c, winapi

Когда я рисую квадрат c помощью функции Rectangle с выбранной кистью brush с определённым цветом, WinApi рисует квадрат НЕ заполненный этим цветом, а заполненный чёрными точками. Причём их количество зависит от цвета, т.е. чем темнее цвет, тем больше точек. Как это исправить?

Выглядит это так:

[image]

Прямоугольник на картинке должен быть красным.

Код:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int x = 0, y = 0;
float time = 0;
int mouse_pos_x, mouse_pos_y;
RECT rect;

void moveSquare(int* cur_x, int* cur_y) {
    float angle = atan2f((float)*cur_x - (float)x, (float)*cur_y - (float)y);
    x += (int)(4.0 * sinf(angle));
    y += (int)(4.0 * cosf(angle));
}

void drawSquare(HDC* dc) {
    HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0)); //CreateSolidBrush(RGB((int)((cosf(time) / 2 + 0.5) * 255.0), (int)((sinf(time) / 2 + 0.5) * 255.0), 0));
    SelectObject(*dc, brush);
    Rectangle(*dc, x, y, x + 100, y + 100);
    DeleteObject(brush);
}

void WinShow(HDC* dc) {
    HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(*dc);
    HBITMAP memBM = CreateCompatibleBitmap(memDC, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);
    SelectObject(memDC, memBM);

    HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
    SelectObject(*dc, brush);
    Rectangle(memDC, 0, 0, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);
    drawSquare(&memDC);
    moveSquare(&mouse_pos_x, &mouse_pos_y);
    DeleteObject(brush);

    BitBlt(*dc, 0, 0, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    DeleteDC(memDC);
    DeleteObject(memBM);
}

LRESULT WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
    if (message == WM_DESTROY)
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    else if (message == WM_CHAR)
        printf("%c", (char)wparam);
    else if (message == WM_MOUSEMOVE) {
        mouse_pos_x = LOWORD(lparam); mouse_pos_y = HIWORD(lparam);
    }
    else if (message == WM_SIZE)
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
    else if (message == WM_PAINT) {
        HDC dc = GetDC(hwnd);
        WinShow(&dc);
    }
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    WNDCLASSW window;
    memset(&window, 0, sizeof(WNDCLASSW));
    window.lpszClassName = L"WND";
    window.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    RegisterClassW(&window);

    HWND hWnd;
    hWnd = CreateWindowW(L"WND", L"Это окно!", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
    MSG msg;
    while (1) {
        if (PeekMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) break;
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        /*}
        else {*/
            Sleep(1);
        }
        time += 0.1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Выглядит как будто у вас монохромный холст. Где вы задаете цветной режим холста?

Comment: @Kromster Вполне возможно, что нет. Как это делается?

Comment: Тут неопределенное поведение из-за того, что `WndProc` не всегда возвращает результат и из-за отсутствия проверок успешности вызванных функций WinAPI. Рисование производится черт знает где. Ресурсы бесконтрольно утекают. Также идет каша из A и W вариантов.

Comment: @user7860670 Насчёт того, что `WndProc`  не всегда возвращает результат - я сделал так, чтобы она делала это всегда, но ничего не поменялось.

Comment: @user7860670 Можно поподробнее? Что значит "чёрт знает где"? Вроде бы и HDC и HWND есть, и что ещё за A и W варианты?

Comment: Рисование почему-то сделано в цикле обработки сообщений, WM_PAINT не обрабатывается. A и W варианты - ansi и wide варианты функций winapi.

Comment: @user7860670 а где должно быть сделано рисование? И я заменил все функции с ansi на wide и ничего не поменялось.

Comment: @user7860670 WM_PAINT в коде - лишняя строка, которую я забыл убрать. Она ничего не делает.

Comment: Ну вот в этом и проблема, это как раз то сообщение, в ответ на которое окно может перерисовать свое содержимое.

Comment: @user7860670 то есть вы хотите сказать, что от того, где вызываются функции рисования, зависит то, будет ли монохромным режим рисования? Если да, то... Я переместил всё это рисование в WM_PAINT и ничего не изменилось

Comment: Я хочу сказать, что из-за всех перечисленных мной проблем тут вообще ничего не должно работать. Сначала стоит разобраться с ними, а уже затем с неправильным цветом.

Comment: @user7860670 Ну, вроде как, я разобрался со всем, теперь я хочу разобраться с цветом) А если это не должно работать, то какая разница, ведь это работает!

Comment: Нет, это не работает... *"я разобрался со всем"* - код в вопросе, как был весь поломан, так и остался, почти ничего не изменилось

Comment: @user7860670 Ну и как же его исправить?) И что же тут конкретно не работает, кроме нормального цвета?

Comment: Я уже перечислил проблемные места в первом комментарии..

Comment: @user7860670 так, ну давайте посмотрим... Насчёт рисования "чёрт знает где" - я переместил его в WM_PAINT, если оно должно быть в другом месте, то скажите, пожалуйста, где. WinApi возвращает значение, что делать с рекурсами непонятно, куда они там унекают - вопрос) Кашу из A и W вариантов я уже исправил - теперь там только W варианты. Что ещё нужно исправить, чтобы всё не было поломано? И наконец, как заставить этот несчастный прямоугольник заливаться цветом, а не точками?

Comment: А теперь откройте документацию к WM_PAINT и прочитайте, для чего служит это сообщение и как его следует обрабатывать. Затем документацию к `GetDC`. Обращая особое внимание на секцию Remarks. Ну и затем проделывайте это для всех вызываемых функций.

Comment: @user7860670 А цвет-то как исправить? Ничего личного, но я задал этот вопрос, чтобы понять, как исправить цвет прямоугольника, а вы мне говорите, что, мол, у меня тут всё поломано и нужно брать и танцевать с бубном над каждой вызываемой функцией, чтобы код не был "сломаным". Если бы мне надо было сделать код красивым, я бы задал вопрос про то, как сделать его красивым! Сначала я хочу понять, как вообще использовать всё это рисование, а уже потом, как сделать его красивым. И начать я хочу с цвета прямоугольника. Если вы не можете мне помочь, бывайте)

Comment: @user7860670 Вы ещё и -1 моему вопросу просто так поставили... Просто прекрасно)